# Parse Push Notification Security

Tags: ios, push-notification, parse-platform, apple-push-notifications

I'm using Parse for push notifications. Is there a way to ensure that malicious users will not hit the Parse API and send fake pushes? Certainly creating the notifications on the server-side helps limit this risk, but how can we prevent malicious use if the system is simply based on subscribing to channels? Is the only way to create sufficiently unique channel names so they can't be guessed? I would imagine there is a way to remove client-side push abilities.

Comment: the attacker needs your certificates, make sure you set strong passphrases. The real big risk is if your sever gets compromised

Comment: Couldn't someone just use the Parse API for sending them, though? If the client has the ability to send a push, couldn't they just send to whatever channel they wanted?

Comment: Note that on Android there are no certs involved. I think they also need your Parse appid and client key, which is a tiny bit more secure.